# How to set limited percentage value using trackbar in c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use trackbar as input in winform application. I want users to only select four % value ie. 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%. [I have added a img of display that I want to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVex4.png) I don't want them to select any intermediate % value.

I was not able to figure out in the trackbar properties.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the max value to 4. Then set the percentage to trackbar value * 25.

Comment: Also set `SmallChange` and `LargeChange` to `1`.

Comment: "Then set the percentage to trackbar value * 25". -- You mean in the code, right?

Comment: Also, can you set labels to marks as shown in image from properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a tooltip on your trackbar.if you just want to get percente values as like %25 , %50 , %75 , %100 and %0 you can do like this:

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
  public form1()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        trackBar1.Maximum = 4;
        trackBar1.SmallChange = 1;
        trackBar1.LargeChange = 1;
        trackBar1.TickFrequency = 1;//This is will set your ticking steps lenght
        }
  private void TrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(trackBar1, "% "+trackBar1.Value*25).ToString());
        }
}
```